# Scroll to next div when a single mousewheel scroll is done

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I'm making a paralax website, and I want to implement the mousewheel scroll to div function. That is whenever I use scroll via my mousewheel, it scrolls to the next or previous div. I tried copying the code from here. But it doesn't work. Sorry, I might look too much of a noob.

Here is my HTML code.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Stamp it Go!</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
                <linkrel="stylesheet"href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nova+Flat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
          <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
          </head>
          <body>
           <div id='cssmenu'>
            <ul>
             <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
             <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
           </ul>
         </div>

        <div class="content">
         <div class="firstscreen" style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="container">
           <div class="video">
            <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/91085172" width="800" height="400 " frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> 
           </div>   
            </div>  
          </div>

      <div class="secondscreen" style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="container" style="padding: 11% 0;">
         <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="pics/reward.jpg" alt="" width="" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-6">
          <ul style="margin-top: 15%;">
           <li class="liitem">Establish YOUR  own Loyalty club</li>
           <li class="liitem">Reward your customers</li>
           <li class="liitem">Categorize your customers(Silver Gold and Platinum)</li>
           <li class="liitem">Stay connected with your customers, anywhere they are.(Lead management system, Social media)</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
      </div>    
      </div>


      <div class="thirdscreen">
        <div class="container" style="padding: 16% 0;">

          <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-6">
            <ul style="margin-top: 13%;">
              <li class="liitem">Understand your Customer</li>
              <li class="liitem">Get insights into Customer behavior</li>
              <li class="liitem">Know your customers special days</li>
              <li class="liitem">Tailor made offers and campaigns to suit your customers</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="<col>-sm-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="pics/customer-reach.jpg" alt="" width="" style="margin-top: 12%;">
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="fourthscreen">
        <div class="container" style="padding: 16% 0;">
         <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="pics/Analytics.jpg" alt="" width="" style="margin-top: 12%;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-6">
          <ul style="margin-top: 13%;">
           <li class="liitem">Analyse, manage and grow your Business</li>
           <li class="liitem">Get insights into your Business</li>
           <li class="liitem">Reach new customers</li>
           <li class="liitem">Speed up your slow hours</li>
           <li class="liitem">Increase footfall traffic and ROI</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
      </div>

      <footer>
        <div class="socialicons">
         <h2 style="font-family:'Nova Flat', cursive; text-align: center; margin: 0; padding-top: 2%;">Reach Us At</h2> <br>
         <div style="padding-bottom: 2%;">
          <img src="pics/facebook.png" alt="" width="4%">
          <img src="pics/twitter.png" alt="" width="3.5%">
          <img src="pics/gplus.png" alt="" width="3.5%">
        </div>  
      </div>
      </div>
      </footer>


      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        (function($){var types=['DOMMouseScroll','mousewheel'];if($.event.fixHooks){for(var i=types.length;i;){$.event.fixHooks[types[--i]]=$.event.mouseHooks;}}
          $.event.special.mousewheel={setup:function(){if(this.addEventListener){for(var i=types.length;i;){this.addEventListener(types[--i],handler,false);}}else{this.onmousewheel=handler;}},teardown:function(){if(this.removeEventListener){for(var i=types.length;i;){this.removeEventListener(types[--i],handler,false);}}else{this.onmousewheel=null;}}};$.fn.extend({mousewheel:function(fn){return fn?this.bind("mousewheel",fn):this.trigger("mousewheel");},unmousewheel:function(fn){return this.unbind("mousewheel",fn);}});function handler(event){var orgEvent=event||window.event,args=[].slice.call(arguments,1),delta=0,returnValue=true,deltaX=0,deltaY=0;event=$.event.fix(orgEvent);event.type="mousewheel";if(orgEvent.wheelDelta){delta=orgEvent.wheelDelta/120;}
          if(orgEvent.detail){delta=-orgEvent.detail/3;}
          deltaY=delta;if(orgEvent.axis!==undefined&&orgEvent.axis===orgEvent.HORIZONTAL_AXIS){deltaY=0;deltaX=-1*delta;}
          if(orgEvent.wheelDeltaY!==undefined){deltaY=orgEvent.wheelDeltaY/120;}
          if(orgEvent.wheelDeltaX!==undefined){deltaX=-1*orgEvent.wheelDeltaX/120;}
          args.unshift(event,delta,deltaX,deltaY);return($.event.dispatch||$.event.handle).apply(this,args);}})(jQuery);

          var Parallax = {
            utils: {
              doSlide: function(section) {
                var top = section.position().top;
                $('.content').stop().animate({
                  top: -top
                }, 600, 'linear', function() {
                  section.addClass('slided').siblings('div.section').removeClass('slided');
                });
              }
            },
            fn: {
              setHeights: function() {
                $('div.section').height($(window).height());
              },
              onSiteScroll: function() {
                var section = null;

                $('.content').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  if (delta < 0) {
                    section = ($('.slided').length) ? $('.slided') : $('.firstscreen');
                    var next = (section.next().length) ? section.next() : $('.firstscreen');
                    Parallax.utils.doSlide(next);
                  }
                  else if(delta > 0) {
                    section = ($('.slided').length) ? $('.slided') : $('.firstscreen');
                    var prev = (section.prev().length) ? section.prev() : $('.firstscreen');
                    Parallax.utils.doSlide(prev);
                  }
                });


              }
            },

            init: function() {
              for (var prop in this.fn) {
                if (typeof this.fn[prop] === 'function') {
                  this.fn[prop]();
                }
              }
            }
          };

          Parallax.init();
        </script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: You might want to use [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use below jquery event for scrolling to next div..

```
$('#....').scroll(function(){
    $('#...').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```